# Alterar Lista com uma função no python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou desenvolvendo alguns exercícios do livro "*Curso Intensivo de Python*" mas travei no exercício 8.10 proposto:

**EX:**
8.10 – Grandes mágicos: Comece com uma cópia de seu programa do
Exercício 8.9. Escreva uma função chamada make_great() que modifique a
lista de mágicos acrescentando a expressão o Grande ao nome de cada
mágico. Chame show_magicians() para ver se a lista foi realmente modificada.

Meu programa do exercicio 8.9 ficou assim:

```
  print("===================== EX-01 ================")
  magicos = ["Mario", "João", "Maria"]
  '''Exibe uma saudação aos magicos'''
  def nomes_dos_magicos(nome):
      for magico in magicos:
          print("Olá,", magico)

saudacao = nomes_dos_magicos(magicos)
```

Minha dificuldade esta em armazenar esse novo valor "Grande" antes dos nomes dentro da lista original e não apenas na função

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar também a função `range`:

```
print("===================== EX-01 ================")
magicos = ["Mario", "João", "Maria"]
'''Exibe uma saudação aos magicos'''
def nomes_dos_magicos():
    for i in range(len(magicos)):
        magicos[i] = "O Grande " + magicos[i]

nomes_dos_magicos()
print(magicos)
```

Ou, se quiser usar *list comprehension*, a função fica assim:

```
def nomes_dos_magicos():
    global magicos
    magicos = ["O Grande " + magico for magico in magicos]
```

Veja que, na prática, é dispensável definir uma função se você usar *list comprehension* neste último caso. Mas, como é um exercício, é isso aí.

Answer (score 0):

Para isso, é necessário alterar o valor da váriavel `mágicos` quando chama a função `nomes_dos_magicos`.

Aqui uso a função `enumerate` para poder aceder ao indíce da lista quando estamos a fazer o `for loop`:

```
print("===================== EX-01 ================")
magicos = ["Mario", "João", "Maria"]
'''Exibe uma saudação aos magicos'''
def nomes_dos_magicos(nome):
  for i, nome in enumerate(magicos):
      magicos[i] = "O Grande " + nome

nomes_dos_magicos(magicos)
print(magicos)
```

Comment: Ahh sim,no caso essa alteração para ***"O grande"*** não seria aplicada a lista original definitivamente, e sim, na chamada da função, por exemplo: quando eu chamasse a função de saudação do exercício anterior essa modificação também deve estar la porque a lista original foi modificada